# Error when i running the application hyperledger fabric

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm following this tutorial:
https://github.com/ITPeople-Blockchain/auction
and at the step: "Build peer and Orderer binaries and Start Orderer", 
at the command: make native

I recived following error:

> Makefile:71: *** "No go in PATH: Check dependencies".  Arresto.

I'm using Ubuntu on VirtualBox and I set the gopath correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go path is not set.

find installed directory of go lang. (e.g linux )

> whereis go

then export below var.

> export GOPATH=$HOME/go export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

these exported variable scope is limited to current terminal only so better to set into file **~/.bashrc**

Answer (score 1):

`GOPATH` may be right, but that's not what the error refers to - it's saying that the `go` command is not in your `PATH`. You need to add `GOROOT/bin` to your `PATH`.

Comment: I set the path so:                                                                                  export GOROOT=$HOME/user/go
export GOPATH=$HOME/user/work
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin

Comment: Is `$HOME/user/go` where go is installed?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm following this tutorial: https://github.com/ITPeople-Blockchain/auction and at the step: "Build peer and Orderer binaries and Start Orderer", at the command: make native

The repository mentioned above has been updated about 2 months ago, while while you'd better try to follow more recently updated: [Get Started](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

> Makefile:71: *** "No go in PATH: Check dependencies". Arresto.

Also note that ^^^ error actually tells you are missing go binary from your `PATH`. Check you have configured `GOPATH`, `GOROOT` and make sure go binary accessible within `PATH`.