# Hyper ledger make file go path

Tags: go, makefile, hyperledger-fabric

Hi I'm trying to start a private hyper-ledger fabric network for testing

When I enter the command `sudo make configtxgen cryptogen`

I get `Makefile:93: *** "No go in PATH: Check dependencies".  Stop.`

This is the path I'm using in my bashrc

```
export GOROOT=/usr/local/go
export GOPATH=/usr/local/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim
export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH
```

go version returns `go version go1.9.1 linux/amd64`

Any help would be appreciated

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when i running the application hyperledger fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723936/error-when-i-running-the-application-hyperledger-fabric)

Comment: There's no reason to set GOROOT, and you probably should avoid it.

Comment: Ive changed to location of fabric and changed GOPATH to point to it and got rid of GOROOT. I've never used go before I'm not sure where GOPATH should be pointing in this context

Comment: @VenomSnake14: is you've never used go before, then read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), or just don't set GOPATH and use the default (the path you've set is wrong for many  reasons)